# How fix this : error: no member named 'setBackgroundColor' in 'QTableWidgetItem'?

Tags: c++, qt

```
ui -> tablica -> item(i, j) -> text().toInt(&f1);
               if(f1)
               {
                   ui -> tablica -> item(i, j) -> setBackgroundColor(Qt::white);
               }
```

Error with method setBackgroundColor.

Comment: It appears that `setBackgroundColor` was removed from Qt6 as the obsolete members of `QTableWidgetItem` are no longer listed in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidgetitem.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: [void QTableWidgetItem::setBackground(const QBrush &brush)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setBackground)

See here why:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem-obsolete.html#setBackgroundColor

> void QTableWidgetItem::setBackgroundColor(const QColor &color)
> This function is obsolete. It is provided to keep old source code working. We strongly advise against using it in new code.
> This function is deprecated. Use setBackground() instead.
> See also backgroundColor().